# Karate-mobile - click the input is not working

Tags: appium, karate, android-testing

The input click event is not working during the mobile android test.`And driver.optional('@Skip').click() - this line works on text link`. Input click with the placeholder element is not working. need help to solve this.

```
 @nuego_login_test
 Feature: Login Test in Nuego app
 Background: App Preset

 Scenario: launch chrome in appium
   * configure driver =
   """
   {
   type: 'android',
   webDriverPath : "/wd/hub",
   start: true,
   httpConfig : { readTimeout: 120000 }
   }
   """
   * def desiredConfig =
   """
   {
   "app":"/home/yabesh/Downloads/app-debug.apk",
   "appPackage":"com.gcm.nuego",
   "newCommandTimeout" : 300,
   "platformVersion" : "5.1",
   "platformName" : "Android",
   "connectHardwareKeyboard" : true,
   "deviceName" : "emulator-554",
   "avd": "Pixel_6_API_27",
   "automationName" : "UiAutomator2",
   "appWaitForLaunch":"false",
   }
   """
   * driver { webDriverSession: { desiredCapabilities : "#(desiredConfig)"} }
   * delay(10000).screenshot()
   And driver.optional('@Skip').click()
   * delay(1000)
   And driver.click('#com.gcm.nuego:id/editTextBox').input("9988774455")-**doesn't work**
   * delay(3000).screenshot()
```

[image]